# What's to the left of the input in a Turing Machine?

Tags: automation, turing-machines

For example, if I'm at the end of the input and I'm shifting left, how would I know I'm at the very beginning of the tape? If there are more |_| before the input, then it would be easy for me to tell I'm at the beginning again, but I don't know if there are any. This isn't a homework question, I am sure the answer is obvious, which is why I can find nothing online about the tape to the left of the input. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In most formulations the tape is infinite in both directions.  Everything except the input section of the tape is initialized to some specified "blank" value.

Comment: alright that's what I thought, but I wasn't 100% sure, thank you.

Comment: Now make the answeror :) happy by accepting his answer, questionor! :)